# HTML 5 audio element not looping in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, audio

I'm trying to use this javascript to loop an audio element:

music.js:

```
myAudio = new Audio('/assets/drumloop.mp3');
myAudio.loop = true;
myAudio.play();
```

When I include this as a script in a plain html file and open the html file in Safari 5.1, it loops just fine. When I include this javascript from my Rails application running on a local rails server, the audio plays, but *does not loop*.

I have tried using a callback on the 'ended' event to set the time to zero and play again (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273552/html-5-audio-looping), but that does not work either.

Is it possible that rails isn't sending enough information in the http header?

Comment: Strange... It works once it's pushed to heroku, so maybe it has something to do with serving precompiled assets... Back to the http header thing... I'll debug this if I get around to it, but in the mean time it's good enough!

Comment: if you don't put it in the asset pipeline, does it still have the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I frequently run into the same issue. I haven't found a *real* solution, but did come of with a "good enough during development" one.

**I ended up throwing my audio files on another server and referencing them from my rails app during development** if I really needed to test looping or seeking.

Apache running on localhost worked fine for me. You could also use a web server. Just make sure to change those paths back before deploying!

Super frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need JS for this. Try this HTML:

```
<audio controls="controls" loop="loop">
  <source src="/assets/drumloop.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

The key is **loop="loop"**

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that it doesn't obey these tags when it's served by the local rails server. I have too much other stuff to do so I haven't had a chance to properly debug it, but as I said, I suspect there's some extra header information it's sending when the audio data is served by heroku.