# The html5 audio can't play again in its "ended" event

Tags: html, audio

I have a audio tag in my page, I bind an event handle to the `ended` event:

```
    $('#audio').bind('ended', function() {
        console.log('ended');//I can see this
        $('#audio')[0].play();// but it could not play again
    });
```

at first I play it:

```
$('#audio')[0].play()
```

the problem is, it can be played, and in the play end,I also coulds see the console info, but it can not be play again,how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you setup jsfiddle.net of your code? Is this any particular browser or all browsers? Is #audio the actual Audio element or a container, maybe ended event is bubbling up to a div called #audio?

Comment: Have you tried pure Javascript - eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273552/html-5-audio-looping