# audio player using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, audio-player

I'm a novice with JQuery and I'm trying to create an audio player for my final exam. I wrote this code but apparently in this way I can't create an Audio element. I'm following a guide on the web and I found this problem because it isn't complete. Precisely I need an audio player that shows on the top the cover image of the song and on the bottom the bar with play and pause commands. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

```js
/*creating an audio element*/
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var song = new Audio("songs/numb.mp3");
      var play = $("img.play");
      var pause = $("img.pause");
      pause.hide();
      /*set of instruction when the play img is pressed*/
      $(".play").click(function(){ 
        play.hide();
        song.play();
        pause.show();
      });
      /*set of instruction when the pause img is pressed*/
      $(".pause").click(function(){ 
        pause.hide();
        song.pause();
        play.show();
      });
    });
```

```css
html,body,div{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    div.container{
      width: 20%;
      height:200px;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 30px;
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    /*div that contains the cover image*/
    div.img{
      width: 100%;  
      height: 80%;
    }
    /*cover image*/
    img.songbackground{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
    /*div that contains play and pause img*/
    div.commands{
      width: 100%;
      height: 20%;
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    /*play img*/
    img.play{
      width: auto;
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
    /*pause img*/
    img.pause{
      width: auto;
      height: 100%;
      float: left;
      object-fit: contain;
    }
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="img">
                    <img class="songbackground" src="http://images.wired.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/1453282239_gatto-9-600x335.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="commands">
                    <img class="play" src="http://tympanus.net/PausePlay/images/play.png">
                    <img class="pause" src="http://tympanus.net/PausePlay/images/pause.png">
                </div>
            </div>   
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Comment: sorry, try now please

Answer (score 1):

it is possible with HTML5 Audio API.

See this getting started tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Here is an excellent library to start with: http://www.createjs.com

and some examples: http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS/demos

as well as the official spec: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html

PS: I took this answer from [Is it possible to create javascript audio player with multiple tracks playing in same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892565/is-it-possible-to-create-javascript-audio-player-with-multiple-tracks-playing-in)

Comment: This answer isn't terribly useful, as it's just a series of links. What if the information at those links changes or the site closes down? Your answer would then be partially if not completely useless to future users. Don't just say it's possible with HTML5's audio API, actually provide an example of how it's possible.

Comment: Sorry boss man, i won't let you down next time. In all seriousness I know but I don't have enough of these dumb points to comment on posts. I would have done that if I could have.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, just specify a proper uri for the audio file. Here's your code without jQuery, just for fun (the sample audio comes from Una Kravets' blog):

```js
function ready(){
  var song = new Audio("http://una.im/audio/counter-increment.mp3");
  var play = document.querySelector("img.play");
  var pause = document.querySelector("img.pause");
  pause.classList.add('hide');
  play.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    play.classList.add('hide');
    song.play();
    pause.classList.remove('hide');
  });
  pause.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    pause.classList.add('hide');
    song.pause();
    play.classList.remove('hide');
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', ready);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="img">
                <img class="background" src="http://orig01.deviantart.net/609d/f/2015/279/a/8/va_various_artists_universal_album_cover_by_liberssky-d9c4gfd.jpg" width="200">
            </div>
            <div class="comandi">
                <img class="play" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Play_font_awesome.svg/2000px-Play_font_awesome.svg.png" alt="play" width="50">
                <img class="pause" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/af/Pause_font_awesome.svg/2000px-Pause_font_awesome.svg.png" alt="pause" width="50">
            </div>
```