# Why does this audio loop?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an ajax call in my code, when a new message comes it plays an audio file but the audio file is playing over and over again even if i didn't set it to loop.

Here's the `<audio>` I used:

```
document.getElementById("notifsound").innerHTML = '<audio autoplay><source src="./uploads/notif.mp3" type="audio/mp3"><p></p></audio>';
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @DanielA.White I edited my question

Comment: does this line get executed multiple times?

Comment: I am not sure but I don't thing it does. The message div only reloads once.

Comment: is it possible you are getting many/periodic notifications which trigger that sound?

Comment: Checkout this answer, see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/3273566/393021

Answer (score 0):

Add `loop=false` as an attribute to the HTML `audio` tag

Comment: It loops more frequently now. It looped like every 2 seconds before