# Canvas game audio soundtrack to loop

Tags: javascript

**The Problem**

I am creating a game using the canvas feature of HTML5, I am very new to Javascript though and I am stuck with how I will loop the audio. I have looked at tutorials but none of them have helped.

**The Question**

How can get the code below to allow the audio to repeat when finished?

```
//music
    var snd = new Audio("Menu.mp3");
    snd.play();
        document.getElementById('mute').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        if ( snd.muted ) {
            snd.muted = false
            evt.target.innerHTML = 'mute'
        }
        else {
            snd.muted = true
            evt.target.innerHTML = 'unmute'
        }
    })
```

Comment: [`<audio loop />`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_loop.asp) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Audio Looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273552/html5-audio-looping)

Comment: What does `canvas` here?

Comment: I had already looked at that post @Mr.Polywhirl but couldnt get my head around looking at that code and then looking at mine so i thought I might as well ask a question. This is music inside of a canvas game, but you are right, it has nothing to do with Canvas here sorry

Comment: Plus this is in Javascript, is it not different implementing in javascript than HTML5?

Comment: I simply added (snd.loop = true;)... just after... (var snd = new Audio("Menu.mp3");)... It now repeats.